# Python requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to call a web requests and Im using Python request module.

I have a requests being served on a machine For ex:55.84.201.228. When I enter it throught the browser it works fine and Im able to view the webpage..

but when I use the requests.get, it does not work..It errors with a socket error..

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://55.84.201.228')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 378, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='55.84.201.228', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 110] Connection timed out)
```

How can I fix this issue?

```
>>>r = requests.get('https://www.cnn.com')
```

This works fine.

Comment: It looks like your connection from the python script is timing out - it can't reach the host. Do you have a proxy set in your browser, or some other setting that differs from the script? Without knowing your network setup this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am making a wild guess here since I can't access your machine but from experience, since you are using https on what I assume is some test server try

```
r = requests.get('https://55.84.201.228', verify=False)
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) certificate verification is on by default.

Comment: Yes Ben you're probably right. However requests does have some history of ssl error masking with timeouts https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/701 so I was expecting maybe a ssl handshake timeout? Just wanted to provide some debugging ideas. Proxy settings as in your comment is probably a better clue.

Comment: @jhnwsk that was over 2 years ago. That's been fixed for about the same length of time.

Comment: @sigmavirus24 you are correct, that might've sounded disrespectful towards requests which is not the case. I stand corrected, I've rushed to answer a question I do not have the answer to. Sorry.